# What is maximum ESD current flowing through the pin for HBM model?

Tags: pins, esd, reliability

I have a given specification HBM ESD tolerance on my IC (For instance 1kV). I just want to estimate the maximum current which will flow on the pin in question and so determinate the clamp point on the snap-back curve.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.esda.org/about-esd/esd-fundamentals/part-5-device-sensitivity-and-testing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Human Body Model, as defined in e.g. JEDEC JS-001, includes a 1.5kohm resistor in series with the strike. Thus the maximum current that could be delivered to the pin is Vstrike/1.5kohm. For example, 1kV tolerance would give a maximum peak strike current of 0.66A.

Comment: "tolerance"????

Comment: OPs terminology. Should this confuse you, you could interchange (susceptibility / sensitivity / robustness) (level / classification) etc.